# Rails Amazon S3 uploader - undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, coffeescript

I followed the Heroku article on creating a Direct to S3 file uploader for my Rails app.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

I did everything the tutorial said, but I wrote the js in coffeescript instead.  (I have also converted it to pure JS and tested, but I still get the following issue:

My JS doesn't pickup the the object created for the Amazon pre-signed post.

In my controller, under *new* is:

```
@s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(
  key: "#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", 
  success_action_status: 201, 
  acl: :public_read
)
```

This code seems fine, and is pretty much exactly as the article says.  The problem is in My *projects.coffee.erb*, the following:

```
formData: '<%= @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>'
```

Turns out:

```
undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
```

The code in my controller should create the @*s3_direct_post* object, but my JS doesn't pick it up.  When executing:   @s3_direct_post  in the Rails Console from  the better_errors/binding_of_caller gems, the object is still nil.

Is there something I am missing here?  Is the JS being executed before the object is created?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the JS is inserted in the HTML before It has the value of the instance variable. You shouldn´t use instance variables in your asset pipeline because of precompiling too.

You can do it if you inserted that code in your html directly

```
<script>
 ...
 formData: '<%= @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>'
 ...
</script>
```

Maybe another solution can be remove

```
//= require_tree .
```

from application.js and change the load of your js in your layout to:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller_name %>
```

but you need to change the load of @s3_direct_post to a before filter function in controller

Comment: Thanks, I've had to bring the JS inline in my HAML, which I'm not usually a fan of, but in this case it must be done.  Thanks again for your input.